# CSS - Prevent font-family and letter spacing from changing margin on div and ul

Tags: html, css

I have a container containing a rotated div and an unordered list. I'm trying to get the div and the list flush with one another. I'm able to do this by changing the margin on the div and/or the unordered list. However, when I change the font-family or letter-spacing of the entire document it changes the spacing between the div and ul.

http://jsfiddle.net/

Open the fiddle and use the inspector to toggle the letter-spacing property on * to see what I mean visually.

```css
    #container {
        z-index: 2147483645;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: grey;
        display: inline-block;
        position: fixed;
    }
    #tab {
        background-color: #9F8F6C;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 100%;
        width: 40px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #tab a {
        position: fixed;
        width: 400px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
        transform-origin:left top;

        font-size: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        color: #F5F5F5;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #my-list {
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        height: 100%;
        width: 65px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    * {
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='tab'>
        <a id='tab-text'>hellloooo</a>
    </div>
    <ul id='my-list'>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just need to change your `letter-spacing` from `*` to `tab`.

For demo purposes I replaced your `ID's` for `classes`(because a ID[#], must be unique in the code) .

So here is a snippet below:

```css
#container {
  z-index: 2147483645;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
}
.tab {
  background-color: #9F8F6C;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  /*letter-spacing:2px  APPLY HERE */
}
.tab a {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: left top;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F5F5F5;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#my-list {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/*DEMO PURPOSES*/

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 2px 
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='tab letter-spacing'>
    <a class='tab-text'>hellloooo</a>
  </div>
  <div class='tab'>
    <a class='tab-text'>hellloooo</a>
  </div>
  <ul id='my-list'>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did fix the spacing problem when I set the letter spacing on the tab. However, I think I found the root of the problem. Using the inline-block elements leaves a gap between elements. This gap size is subject to change when the font-size or letter-spacing changes. I floated the elements instead of using inline-block and I was able to freely change the global letter spacing without the layout changing.

Comment: yes `inline-block`creates a gap, I didn't know that was that you were looking for. but in that case you check [this](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: I didn't fully understand the problem when I posted the question so I wasn't able to phrase it right. That was the article that made me realize what was going on and led me to use the floats instead :) I didn't really care about the gap being there. I just didn't like that the gap size changed (and broke the layout) when I changed the font settings.